# Endpoint for Recycle Bin using REST API

Tags: office-365, file, onedrive-for-business, recycle-bin

I have the following endpoint which works fine if I use the file/folder id or 'root' instead of 'RecycleBin', but I just can't seem to get access to the recycle bin using this type of endpoint.

```
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/RecycleBin
```

Using this as the endpoint works, but I'm not sure how to establish what the user tenant is - plus it returns XML rather than JSON, which is not really what I'm after.

```
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username_tenant/_api/web/RecycleBin
```

Any ideas?